# Android: Exception passing anonymous class as Intent parameter

Tags: java, android, serializable, anonymous-class

The Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = MyClass$2)
```

The (simplified) code:

```
i.putExtra("myparam", generateA(context, "foo"));
...
private A generateA(final Context context, String foo) {
    return new A() {

        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface A extends Serializable {

    public void test();

}
```

What am I doing wrong? What I'm passing is a Serializable.

Comment: Is there any more code you can provide us... i cannot see any issues with what is supplied, or post the stack trace

Comment: Oh well... I looked again in the stacktrace and the reason is that the outer class is not Serializable! So I made it implement Serializable. But it has an intance variable of class Handler which is not Serializable and now it's failing because of that.

Comment: Please implement `Parcelable` instead, as it is much faster for use with `Intent` extras. Personally, I would never dream of using an anonymous inner class with `Parcelable` or `Serializable`.

Comment: I'm doing this because I want to pass behaviour to my activity, to be executed. So I made an interface and pass subclasses of it to the activity to execute a certain method. Since I only need these subclasses once, for very specific things, I decided to use anonymous. What exactly is wrong with the approach? How could I do that better?

Comment: More details: My activity is a "generic" one, which only shows a loading screen while it's doing something in the background. This task to be executed in the background is what I'm trying to pass. Another solutions I could think about is pass some kind of identifier and intantiate the correspoding class in the activity using something like a switch case. But it's more elegant passing an  implementation of the interface, because that way my activity doesn't have to know details about what I'm passing.

Comment: On the other side it's kind of stupid when I think that it has to be serialized and deserialized. But it's the "Java way" I would think about passing certain behaviour to a client (which would be the activity) to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, the intent fails because your anonymous class cannot be serialized because of its Handler?

Is it possible to implements your handler in the target activity? The bahaviour class should contain just the behaviour function with a handler provided by the target activity:

```
private transient Handler h;

//Called by the activity in the onCreate
void setHandler(Handler h){
   this.h = h;
}

//Called by the activity to start the behaviour function
void startBehaviour (){
  //...
  //The activity handler will call startHandlerBehaviour itself
  h.sendMessage();
}

//Called by the activity in the Handler to execute in the good context
void startHandlerBehaviour() {
  //...
}
```